# How to change progressbar fill color by css

Tags: javascript, html

I use color picker option in my html template. I do not change progressbar fill color by css because progress bar fill color change from javascript code.
how can i change it by css code.
I include this plugin here

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    function animateElements() {
        $('.progressbar').each(function () {
            var elementPos = $(this).offset().top;
            var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
            var percent = $(this).find('.circle').attr('data-percent');
            var percentage = parseInt(percent, 10) / parseInt(100, 10);
            var animate = $(this).data('animate');
            if (elementPos < topOfWindow + $(window).height() - 30 && !animate) {
                $(this).data('animate', true);
                $(this).find('.circle').circleProgress({
                    startAngle: -Math.PI / 2,
                    value: percent / 100,
                    thickness: 14,
                    fill: {
                        color: '#1B58B8'
                    }
                }).on('circle-animation-progress', function (event, progress, stepValue) {
                    $(this).find('div').text((stepValue*100).toFixed(1) + "%");
                }).stop();
            }
        });
    }

    // Show animated elements
    animateElements();
    $(window).scroll(animateElements);
});
```

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/1f58u1o5/31/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the charts are being drawn in canvas. So, you can't specify the fill color in your CSS. You have to do it in your JS.

If you don't mind adding some extra data to your `div`s, then a quick hack could be the code below (working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1xdxx6w7/)):

```html
<!--                                          HERE ====|    -->
<div class="progressbar" data-animate="false" data-fill-color="#ff000">
  <div class="circle" data-percent="100">
    <div></div>
    <p>Testing</p>
  </div>
</div>
<!--                           DIFFERENT COLOR HERE ====|    -->
<div class="progressbar" data-animate="false" data-fill-color="#000">
  <div class="circle" data-percent="30.5">
    <div></div>
    <p>Testing</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('.progressbar').each(function() {
  // ...

  value: percent / 100,
  thickness: 14,

  fill: {
     color: $(this).data('fill-color')    // <=====  HERE
  }

  }).on('circle-animation-progress', function(event, progress, stepValue) {
  // ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Uzbekjon . But i use a color changing option like this template https://devitems.com/html/resta-preview/resta/index.html  
when i click color change button, how to change fill color ?

Comment: That will not work. You will have to redraw your canvas elements using this plugin.

Comment: Yes , You are right @Uzbekjon . Have any option like that- when i click color change button , page was reload and redraw my canvas color as well as theme color ??

Comment: You will have to google for some other library that allows you do that or ask this as a separate question. If I answered your question, please mark it as a n "answer" and close this question.